# How to make this texture? (Table Wood Texture)

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, texture-painting, procedural

**I want to make the white lines appear on the legs of table in blender (just like in reference image attached). I am not good at procedural textures, if anyone can help. Thank You**[image]

Comment: This is a pretty solid video showing an easy way to do it - Just replace the brown in the ColorRamp with shades of grey. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbAdconaRJo

Comment: Thanks I would definitely take a look. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a *Wave Texture* node before a ColorRamp, or another kind of texture that you stretch on the Z axis, use another texture before if it needs to be a bit deformed, but *Wave Texture* has a *Distortion* value:

[image]

Comment: That looks great. Thank You for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: no bump node!? i am bit disappointed...but yeah +1 because answer within 30 mins, nice screenshots....and damn easy to use answer! ;) I am so happy to know you Clark! ;)

Comment: that's just a beginning, I can make it more complicated but I wanted to stay as simple as possible, then the user can add bumps and glossy and everything of course, by the way, I know Robin and Batfinger are working on a Python version, but I count on you to show the molecular level of wood with geometry nodes, Albert